# Merging a previously created branch to the recently created branch

Tags: git, version-control, merge

I don't know how common this problem is but I can't seem to get a good grasp on how to elegantly solve this merging issue.

So, I started with a master branch. After couple of commits, I created a new branch (let's call it a *wrapper* branch) and then continued working on it (with few commits). I was satisfied with it but at the same time I had done some extra work on master branch too with multiple commits. And then I realized that it was best for me to create a *develop* branch and make that as my primary *dev* branch. So I again created a branch from the master and named it *develop* branch.

And now I realize that it's best for me to merge my *wrapper* branch to *develop* branch instead of master branch. I tried:-

```
git checkout wrapper;
git rebase develop;
```

But this doesn't seem to work. I still don't see changes of my *wrapper* in my *develop* branch. How do I go about solving this problem?

I've also attached an image to better visualize the scenario.

[image: Merging a perviously created branch to the recently created branch]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to checkout develop and inside that branch merge the other into it.
Remember that generally whatever branch you are on is the one you are modifying.

```
git checkout develop
```

then

```
git merge wrapper
```

Comment: Wow, do I feel stupid for asking this now. I thought it would require me to store that branch temporarily like rebase does and then merge it to the branch. Didn't know it would be this ridiculously simple. But just so I get why, is it because there are no commits overlapping between the two?

Comment: @shriek: see my (long) answer, which describes the mechanics git uses to achieve a merge.

Answer (score 2):

You may not want `rebase`, and if you do, you probably want it used a bit differently.

Let me redraw this as ASCII text first, so that I can illustrate.  Note that this is the same as your graphic, except I'm not sure what the brief split (with no intervening nodes) in the line from `master` to `develop` is supposed to indicate.  As with your diagram, a round dot (`o`) represents an individual commit, but I'll mark one in particular with `*` for discussion below, and one with an `x`:

```
o - * ------------------- o - o - o - o   <-- master
      \                                 \
        x - o - o - o   <-- wrapper       o - o - o   <-- develop
```

---

Now let's take a look at what `git rebase` does:

```
git checkout wrapper
git rebase develop
```

The `rebase` command really does a series of `cherry-pick` operations.  Each `cherry-pick` *copies* a commit: it compares the "source" commit to its parent to see what changed, then tries to do the same changes to the target-commit, and make a new commit.  So let's pretend to manually cherry-pick `x`, the first `wrapper`-only commit, adding it to the end of `develop`.  We do this by getting a `git diff` of `x` and `*` to see what changed.  Then we check out the tip of branch `develop` (its last `o` node), but *don't* get on the branch (so that `develop` keeps pointing to its last `o`).  We make the same changes, and `git commit` the result, using the same message as commit `x`.  Assuming all goes well, this gives us a copy, let's call it `x'`, hanging off the end of `develop`:

```
o - * ------------------- o - o - o - o   <-- master
      \                                 \
        x - o - o - o   <-- wrapper       o - o - o   <-- develop
                                                    \
                                                      x'
```

Now we repeat with the remaining three `o`s on `wrapper`, working left to right, extending our anonymous branch.  This gives us:

```
o - * ------------------- o - o - o - o   <-- master
      \                                 \
        x - o - o - o   <-- wrapper       o - o - o   <-- develop
                                                    \
                                                      x'- o'- o'- o'
```

That's almost all there is to it: we've done the entire rebase, except for one thing.  The name `wrapper` still points to the tip of the old commits, instead of the new copies.  So we erase the old label and make it point to the latest:

```
o - * ----------- o - o - o - o   <-- master
      \                         \
        x - o - o - o             o - o - o   <-- develop
                                            \
                                              x'- o'- o'- o'   <-- wrapper
```

Those old commits remain in the repository, but have no (direct) name any more: they've been "abandoned".  (They still have a few ways to find them, but those eventually expire, and then `git gc` can remove them and reclaim space.  You have at least 30 days by default to get them back, though.)

---

If that's not what you want, what are your other options?  Well, you could rebase `wrapper` onto `master`:

```
                        x'- o'- o'- o'   <-- wrapper
                      /
o - * - o - o - o - o     <-- master
      \               \
        x ...           o - o - o   <-- develop
```

and then rebase `develop` onto `wrapper` (this requires a more complicated command line, to tell rebase to take only the three `develop` commits: we can use `git rebase --onto wrapper master develop` for this):

```
                                        o'- o'- o'   <-- develop
                                      /
                        x'- o'- o'- o'   <-- wrapper
                      /
o - * - o - o - o - o     <-- master
      \               \
        x ...           o ...
     [old wrapper]    [old develop]
```

That might be what you want, or it might not.  So there's one more, pretty simple, option: use `git merge`, instead of any of these `rebase` options.

---

What `git merge` does is best described as:

- Find the merge-base of two commits.
- Compare the merge-base to the first of the two commits, giving "what's happened here".
- Compare the merge-base to the other of the two commits, giving "what's happened over there".

The first commit is *always* "where you are now".  Let's say you're on branch `develop`, so this is the tip—the last commit at the right—of branch `develop`, where the label `develop` points.  The other commit is whatever commit you name: if you say `git merge wrapper`, it means the tip of branch `wrapper`.

In this case, the merge-base is the commit marked `*`, because that's the point where, going leftward from `wrapper` and going leftward from `develop`, the two lines first meet.

So, git does a `git diff` of `*` and "tip of `develop`".  That's everything you've done since `*`, on the chain of `master` and then `develop`.

Next, git does a `git diff` of `*` and "tip of `wrapper`".  That's everything you've done on branch `wrapper`, in this case (since we're using the original, un-rebased `wrapper` that comes right off commit `*`).

Now git does its best to combine these two sets of changes, by starting with the current commit<sup>1</sup> (that's the tip of `develop`, again) and "redoing" all the changes that are in the *second* diff, as long as they're not also *already* in the *first* diff.

In other words, if, somewhere in `wrapper`, you fixed the spelling of a word, but then you did the same thing in `master` or `develop` too, git says: aha, this change is already in, I can skip it.  Or, if you deleted a bunch of wrong stuff in `wrapper`, but you did the same in `master` or `develop`, again git sees that it's already done, and skips it.

This all works surprisingly well given that git only knows "these lines were added, these others were deleted" and similar low level stuff.  It has no idea which spelling of some word is correct, for instance.  It just combines the changes.  It's up to *you* to make sure git gets this right.  (This is true for cherry-pick / rebase as well, so there's no advantage to either method here.)

In any case, if git successfully combines the two diffs, it makes a new commit from the resulting files.  The special thing about this new commit is that it has *two* parents, instead of just one: the merge commit "points back" to both the current commit (the old tip of `develop`, in this case), and also to the merged-in commit (the tip of `wrapper`).  As with any new commit, the branch you're on advances to point to the new commit, too.  So this now looks like:

```
o - * ------------------- o - o - o - o   <-- master
      \                                 \
        x - o - o - o   <-- wrapper       o - o - o - M   <-- develop
                      \______________________________/
```

The merge action—combining the diffs—effectively brings in all the changes from branch `wrapper`, making it safe to delete the branch-label itself:

```
git branch -d wrapper
```

(unless you want to hang on to the label, so as to make more commits on it for instance).

(Of course, things may go wrong during the diff-combining; `git merge` may stop and need you to manually resolve conflicts.  If so, you have to do the final `git commit` to create merge `M`, or use `git merge --abort` to stop the attempt to merge and put things back in their original states.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Actually, `git merge` starts with whatever is in the work-tree.  However, the documentation advises making sure that the work-tree is clean (that `git status` shows nothing modified), since if the merge does fail, getting the original state back, including whatever was modified-but-not-committed, can be tricky.

Comment: My god this might be the most detailed response I've ever got in SO. I would have marked this as correct one but it's been handed out already. :(